# Is there some free service to store Geo POIs and REST retrieval

Tags: android, web-services, rest, geolocation, gps

I want to create an Android app that stores and retrieves Geo POIs online, and I'm looking for some online easy to use infrastructure to provide this service.

is there anything like this?
the first thing that comes to my mind is NoSQL databases and CouchDB but I'm not sure if this will cover all my requirements.

I need your advice.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you want your app to use an internet accessible webservice to store POI/geolocation data, but rather than use a generic "cloud db" like Google DataStore or Amazon RDS, you want something that is specific to GeoLocation data.

If this is correct, then you can make use of a feature of the Google Maps/Places API called Place Actions.  This basically lets you store your own data on top of existing POIs in their places DB:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/actions